# Docusign Redirect URL Not Registered Properly Error

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Power Automate for all my API calls to Docusign. I want to be able to capture the authorization code when a user logs into Docusign and then run a flow to get access and refresh tokens.

My flows work when I *manually* copy the authorization code from a localhost redirection browser session and get the user tokens. I want to be able to redirect to a power automate webhook URL so that when the user logs in, the authorization code is redirected to the power automate webhook trigger where I can grab the authorization code and process it to get user tokens. As an example, I have set up a power automate HTTP webhook trigger and have a URL provided by MS to point to.

```
https://prod-63.westus.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/887839a887d945919f8a0bb1aa89d2fa/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=_3pQLhhEORjAAe3V_IjCPNgBYnHnw2nrdP-oEoIPvyA
```

I registered this in Docusign as a redirect URL. No configuration or format error was indicated when registering this URL.

When I attempt to log in via a browser session, after entering my credentials, I get a redirection URL not properly registered error.

Are there format or length or other parameters that prohibit the use of this type of URL as a redirection in Docusign?

Answer (score 0):

I'm 90% certain that the URL you are using is dynamic

The `sig=_3pQLhhEORjAAe3V_IjCPNgBYnHnw2nrdP-oEoIPvyA`

Represent something that will not be the same next time and therefore, my hunch is that it won't do no good to add this type of URL to the list of **redirectURI**.

You can check to make sure I'm right by looking at the URL you get when you get the error.

If I'm right, then you would have to change your approach to this.
If I'm wrong, then maybe there's some issue with some special character or some other inconsistency and I can ask our engineers to look into this.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

The URL is dynamic in a sense that it is created when a "HTTP request is received" flow trigger is created. It remains 'static" to that flow trigger until the flow is deleted. This is how Power Automate creates a webhook to trigger from external events.

The URL is accepted by Docusign when registering the URL as a redirect but it shows the error when executed. I suspect it maybe the special characters as you suggest that might be causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you should use the `Custom Connector Authorization section` of your connector instead of your current approach.

See this [doc](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/verifying-oauth-configuration-for-custom-connectors-ceadbd1d-5a44-5615-208b-029f7ffe6107)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I initially  used custom connectors with full Oauth2 authentication and using POSTMAN to test the API requests.  I found that once the tokens had expired with Docusign, the connectors would 'fail' in the flow. They would not invoke a new sign on session with Docusign. I would see the error with the connector and would have to manually select 'fix it' to restore connector functionality. I took the current approach of maintaining user tokens (once I manually obtained the authorization code) and using the refresh token method to keep the tokens current.